# Oracle Select Query, distributing frequency of labels

Tags: sql, oracle

If i know how much data i am receiving, i can distribute the appearance of a label in this way:

```
select 
  value_column
, CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(VALUE_DATE, 'mm') = '01' and MOD(extract(year from VALUE_DATE), 3) = 0
    THEN TO_CHAR(VALUE_DATE, 'MON-yyyy') 
    else ' '
    END VALUE_DATE_STRING
from SomeTable
```

this will show the data label on January every 3rd year.

[image]

Now, if i don't know how many years are coming back, i'd like to figure this out in the same select and display a total of 5 labels.

i reckon i'd need something like this (pseudo code):

```
CASE WHEN MOD(allRows / 5, ROW_NUM) = 0
```

i guess the only challenging part is getting the allRows in the same select.. since i'm calling this sql from a telerik report, there's limited support for declaring vars and running multiple statements..

Comment: `to_number(TO_CHAR(VALUE_DATE, 'yyyy'))` can be simplified to `extract(year from value_date)` and `TO_CHAR(VALUE_DATE, 'mm')` to `extract(month from value_date)`

Comment: I think `width_bucket` could be what you are looking for: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions234.htm#SQLRF06163

Comment: What is your full query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff not much else.. updated my question

Comment: @SonicSoul . . . You realize that the Januarys may not be evenly distributed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i'm not asking to use a specific month. my question is how to choose 5 random distributed dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
select value_column,
       (CASE WHEN mod(rownum, trunc(cnt / 5)) = 0 o
             THEN TO_CHAR(VALUE_DATE, 'MON-yyyy') 
             else ' '
        END) as VALUE_DATE_STRING
from (select t.*, count(*) over () as cnt
      from SomeTable t
     ) t;
```

It might be `trunc((cnt - 1) / 5)`.

DIT:

If this does what you want, you don't need a CTE or subquery.  I just thought that it made more sense this way (and the subquery does not effect performance).  You can do:

```
select value_column,
       (CASE WHEN mod(row_number() over (order by value_date),
                      trunc(count(*) over () / 5)) = 0
             THEN TO_CHAR(VALUE_DATE, 'MON-yyyy') 
             else ' '
        END) as VALUE_DATE_STRING
from SomeTable t;
```

By the way, you should include `order by` if you are using `rownum`.  Oracle does not guarantee the ordering of rows in a result set without an `order by`.

Comment: hmm i see what you did there... i like thatcount(*) over () .. trying

Comment: ah, it's a nice shortcut, but i need to use the count within the same select.. so would need to go one level deeper on the CTE ..

Comment: rownum doesn't appear to follow the "order by" clause. so i get random numbers in that column. tha's why i went to row_count because that can be ordered ?

Comment: I think you want `row_number()`.

Comment: that's what i am using.. but it would get messy if i added all that into that case statement.. checking..

Answer (score 0):

here's my solution.. it could still be optimized, and i believe the rounding will not always work in my favor..

```
WITH base as ( 
    select 
      value_column
    , value_date
    , cnt.c
    , case mod(c,2) when 0 then 6 else 5 end as divider -- get 5 or 6 dates.. try to minimize truncation consequences.. this may need work. 
    , row_number() over (order by value_date) as row_number
    from MyView
    left join (select count(*) c from MyView where id = 250170) cnt on 1=1
    where id = 250170 
    order by value_date
)
select 
      value_column
    , value_date
    , CASE WHEN MOD(row_number, trunc(c/divider)) = 0
        THEN TO_CHAR(VALUE_DATE, 'MON-yyyy') 
        else ' '
        END VALUE_DATE_STRING
from base
order by value_date
```

**UPDATE**

simplified based on Gordon's answer

```
select 
      value_column
    , value_date
    , (
        CASE WHEN 
            mod(
                row_number() over (order by value_date), 
                trunc(count(*) over () / 5)) = 0
        THEN TO_CHAR(VALUE_DATE, 'MON-yyyy') 
        else ' '
        END) as LABEL_STRING

from MyView
```